# Elementary Matrix and Row Operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find an elementary matrix **E** such that **EA** = **B**

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} -4 & 2 \\ 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}*E=\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 2 \\ 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

So the Elementary Matrix is an Identity Matrix that has one elementary row operation performed on it. Multiplying an Elementary Matrix by **A** should result in a matrix that is equivalent to having that elementary row operation performed onto **A**.

I can see that only the first row of **A** is modified to obtain **B** and I can tell that the first row of **A** is scaled by a value of -2.

Therefore the Elementary Matrix should be the Identity Matrix with the first row scaled by -2.$$\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

However, $$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}≠\begin{bmatrix} -4 & 2 \\ 5 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Do you require  AE=B  or  EA=B?  you've implied both in your question.

Comment: I made an error in regards to the order. This was pretty dumb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the operation is $B=EA$ we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 0\\0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1\\5 & 3
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-4 & 2\\5 & 3
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Your elementary matrix is correct but you meant to multiply it to $A$ on the left not on the right.

Answer (score 3):

I would look at what the question is asking versus what your calculations.

The question is asking to find a matrix $E$ (the elementary row operation matrix) such that $EA = B$. But in your attempt at the problem you try to find $E$ by solving the equation $AE=B$, which will get you a different solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply solve the below equation for $E$.

$$EA=B$$

That is,

$$EA=B  \Longrightarrow  EAA^{-1}=BA^{-1}   \Longrightarrow   E=BA^{-1} .$$

So all you need is to find the inverse of $A$, and you're done.

Comment: What if A does not have an inverse? Moreover, this method is not necessarely easy to implement.

Comment: @Martigan  I understand, but I was giving a method for this particular case.   $A$ is invertible and it's straightforward to find the inverse of a 2x2 matrix, hence my suggestion.